# Assigning IP addresses manually

Tags: networking, router, mac, ip, tcp

I have internet connection from a local ISP at home. I see other routers and their IP addresses on my network using wireshark, when I connect the ethernet cable from ISP directly to my laptop using bridged connection. What if I assign myself a IP address manually and set the local gateway as one of these routers? Will internet work?

I tried doing that, and it did, in fact, work. I don't understand how this is happening. Any explanation to this?

Comment: I assume you are seeing broadcast packets?  Can you just set you router to drop those packets? Also hopefully your laptop is running a firewall, you're a bare naked lady just plugging your self in with a I assume public IP, versus Nating.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a router to connect **one device** to the internet.

You need a router with NAT to share the connection with with **multiple TCP/IP compliant devices.**

> "I see other routers and their IP addresses on my network using
> wireshark"

~ **This isn't your network**. You are most likely seeing the **ISP switched network**
routers, (the inter-ISP Network), or the unlikely scenario that the ISP network isn't properly segregated, and you are seeing your neighbors routers WAN interfaces in Wireshark.

You should exercise caution when doing this, If the Network interface is in Promiscuous mode you should be OK. If the Network Interface has a Global IP Address, you could be exposing the PC **to the wild without a firewall.** (Depending on OS & configuration).

Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: Was this explanation useful?

Comment: That didn't answer my question. How am I able to connect to the internet?